# If $m,n$ are relatively prime, are there an infinitude of primes $mx^2 +n$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I know that Dirichlet's theorem says that there are an infinite number of primes of the form $mx+n$

I was wondering what we know when $x$ is squared.

If for any reason we don't know if there are infinite primes, can we say anything about the number of semiprimes of this form?

Thanks,

-Larry

Comment: we do not know about primes, even for $x^2 + 1.$ I half remember results on semiprimes, no name comes to mind yet.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture

Comment: If $m = 1$ and $n=-1$ it's not true.

Comment: Good point.  So, it wouldn't be true if $m$ is a square and $n$ is a negative square.  And as long as it doesn't divide into more than two factors, there might be an infinite number of semiprimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, Iwaniec has shown that infinitely many $x^2 + 1$ are either prime or semiprime. Maybe other polynomials as well.  https://oeis.org/A248742

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  Very interesting.

Comment: Will: Oliver's paper (referenced in the OEIS link you give) does generalize Iwaniec's result to all irreducible polynomials without a fixed divisor.

Comment: @Charles, thanks. I've met Oliver; he wrote something on my stuff (with Kaplansky and Schiemann) in a chapter of his dissertation, not sure that it got separate publication. Result was that all our examples really do work as we thought if one assumes a generalized RH. Ah: item 9 here: http://web.stanford.edu/~rjlo/research.html  He says there his real last name is Lemke Oliver, two words with a space rather than a hyphen.

Comment: @WillJagy: Thanks for the correction! I wasn't sure how to parse the name.

Comment: @Charles, I had no idea either.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an open problem. See for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions#Generalizations . And a solution, if we ever find one, will probably be much more advanced than just elementary number theory. So you might want to edit your tags.

Comment: Thanks.  I've changed "Elementary-Number-Theory" to "Number-Theory'.